# How does Objectify query works

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Suppose I have this code:

```
    Query<Car> q = ofy().load().type(Car.class);
    for (Car car : q) {
        // Do something with car...
    }
```

How does  `Query<T>` works, suppose the datastore contains million records, will `Query` load all `Car` objects into the memory or it will fetch it one by one from the datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [chunk size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914069/google-app-engine-chunksize-prefetchsize-where-can-i-read-details-on-it) is 30 - see [here](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/cmd/QueryImpl.java). Prefetch size is not set so it defaults to chunk size.

So, iterator will fetch 30 Entities at a time.