# Mass update queues

Tags: google-app-engine

I see a very common requirement to update a field or value of all the rows of a particular entity type and it usually crosses 10 min queue limit.

So, what is the best way to run a cron job using task queues which can finish updation of all the rows ?

One of the approach i tried was firing a query in the cron job and then creating multiple list of ids of equally size like say each list contains 100 ids. and then spwaning one task per list by passing the id list. Then in the task code geting the entity row using

pm.getObjectId and then processing it.

I still find this approach a bit manual and not  intelligent. Any better ways to handle it?

Comment: If you have to perform an operation on all of your rows, batching sets of IDs into individual tasks is a perfectly reasonable way to do it. What's "manual and not intelligent" about it?

Comment: well that's my feeling about it. I would hope to get it some smart way like when the time limit is about to approach it may just close the persistence mnanager to save till that data and then can spawn a new thread to resume from there. i think spwaning the thread etc is still doable but resuming from where it left will make the overall stuff intelligent and more generic

Comment: If you split things into batches you can potentially run them in parallel, which is a superior solution to running them linearly and "resuming where things left off".

Comment: true but here in this case i dont need a fast but something self managed.

Comment: Then use a [backend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/) which can run indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have cash to burn, use a backend; they have no limits (though using a backend to process a single large request is wasteful...  Only consider this if you have other work you can offload to it).

More likely, what you really want to do is sharding.  That is, breaking up one big linear task into a bunch of smaller, parallelizable tasks.

Once common pattern I use a lot is to have one request just do dispatching...  That is, query on the work you need to do, collect up a list of keys to operate on, and fire off batches of work with, say, 100 tasks at a time (send along as much data as you can scrape to avoid re-querying if you don't need to).

This way, only the dispatcher has to navigate the complete dataset, without performing any time-consuming updates, and so long as it takes less than 10 minutes, you should be golden.

Now, depending on your entity ancestor setup, you might run into contention trying to update thousands of entities in parallel (which can happen if your dispatcher is too fast).  The simple solution is to set .withCountDownMillis((latency+=1000)) to give each request about a second of breathing room (maybe more, depending on the size of your entities and the number of indexes on each one).  Benchmark your app w/ appstats to see how long each actually takes, and give them an extra 500 or so millis to cover standard deviation.

Now... I also have to wonder how many entities you are working on that 10 minutes isn't long enough...  Are you using asynchronous api?  How about batching requests?  If you are operating on one entity at a time, and blocking on get/put per entity, you will easily hit the limit.

Instead, look into asynchronous requests.  Using async, I am able to fire off a put, stash the Future, fire off a bunch more, and then by the time I finalize the Future, the operation is already completed, and I pay essentially 0milli wall time blocking on requests.

Even if you can't use low-level async (still, highly recommended), consider at least using batches.  That is, instead of putting one at a time, use a list and do a put + clear every 50 entities or so (more if they are small).  This allows appengine internal backend to parallelize all fifty, so you pay the time for 1+ per entity serialization overhead.

Combining both async and batching with non-contentious entities, I am generally able to process roughly 4000 entities a minute.  And if you have to do 40,000+ entities, then you need to look into proper sharding.  To do so, grab one key every (arbitrarily chosen) 1000 entities, and launch a task which queries from previous key (or null) to next key.  This allows you to run over as many entities as you please in a short time by taking a big job and turning it into more smaller jobs.

Comment: If you have cash to burn, use a backend; ? So the dynamic backends arent't they perfect for not wasting cash?

Comment: there are 7000 entities at this moment which i need to process. And for each entity i need to create two additional entities. So, in all you can say: 7000 traversals and 14000 entities need to be created.

Comment: to add on i cannot do batching here as i am creating two entities as one operation and 2nd entity need first entity's key as foreign key. So, creating first 50 entities of type A and then associating them to 50 child entities will make it even more complex.

Comment: The difference between doing one and then another or doing fifty and then another fifty is to use a list instead of an instance.  It might feel more complex, but if you abstract away the process, iterating through the lists isn't really that much more difficult.  And it will save you considerable money (try it with appstats and you will see what I mean).

Comment: Re: Cash to Burn; if you have other work you can move off to the backend and actually make use of it, then it's a smart move that will save you money (especially if you take advantage of longer-than-request background threads).  If, however, you just have one big job you need to run, you won't be able to hit peek usage even on a B1.  If the orange line isn't hovering near the blue line (usage versus charges), then you are losing money.  If you can shard that one big task into lots of parallel tasks, you can save money by not paying per request, but one big serial task = backend costs more.

Comment: how do u use appstats couldnt find anything on it ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats

Just beware, you can't use them properly on backends by default, there was a hack I had to do, but I can't remember it offhand.  If you have any troubles, jfgi :)

Comment: by the way how to exclude only /appstat requests ? they are not needed to be monitored but rest everything is as of now

Answer (score 1):

I use this to update millions of records within task queue 10min limit:

1. Create a loop where in each iteration you run a [query with cursor](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Query_Cursors) (do not use `offset()`). In each iteration use next cursor. This way you will efficiently walk the whole range of targeted entities. Use `limit(1000)` to each time get a batch of 1000 entities. Also [set the prefetch size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914069/google-app-engine-chunksize-prefetchsize-where-can-i-read-details-on-it) to 1000 to minimize network roundtrip.
2. For each batch, update the properties and then do [async put](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/async).